# How to make Sign In tab to your web site using Google Plus Tab?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

Although sign in tab has been created I haven't been able to store the user's info into my database! I need the code in Java and API in Java if there is so

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific here... it's hard to understand what you want..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are asking for here, but if you need advice on integrating Google+ Sign-in using Java, check out our quickstart to see how we did it.  The instructions can be found at https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java.  Or you can check out our GitHub page to see the code directly at https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/.